# Word for when someone gets into a job/role due to being related to someone

Tags: single-word-requests

It's a word that suggests that educated or talented people who aren't related don't stand a chance. The word is why Peaches Geldof is famous today.

It is a real word, I just forgot the word.

Comment: Although *nepotism* is obviously the word you seek, it's not obvious to me that Peaches Geldoff is an example of the process at all, let alone an archetype. She's a journalist, television presenter and model, but I'm not aware her father has ever given her a job that a non-relative wouldn't have got.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sure, I agree this isn't in fact nepotism, but she would never have had those breaks if she happened to be a random teenager, if say, she was Peaches Fingers instead of Geldof.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If someone gets a job by being related to someone, it's [nepotism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nepotism)

> Favoritism granted to relatives or friends regardless of merit.The word nepotism is from the Latin word nepos, nepotis (m. "nephew"), from which modern Romanian nepot and Italian nipote, "nephew" or "grandchild" are also descended.

Peaches Geldof seems to be quite a successful journalist/columnist, television presenter/model celebrity. Probably businesswoman too. I don't know, but I doubt she has no talent at anything she's famous/rich for, and I doubt her father gives or gets her jobs. She's an example of a [privileged](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/privileged) person. Specifically, as @Tom Au notes, one who is [(well-)connected](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/well-connected).

Comment: @CoderAtHeart: I can but try! I just shamelessly stole Tom's *connected*, and dropped that in. As the correct answer to OP's "second" question *(word for easier route to success by virtue of famous parents)*. So now it should be twice as correct! :)

Comment: That just shows your cogency.

Answer (score 18):

*[Nepotism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nepotism)* is the word you're looking for, although it actually describes any situation where an undue advantage is given to a personal friend or relative in a situation where people should be judged on merit alone.

Comment: +1: You got in three seconds before FumbleFingers, I see – here's a cookie‮

Answer (score 8):

The other word I would use is **connected**.

That is, you give a job to someone because you really want to do business with the "connected" person's parent, spouse, sibling, etc.

Nepotism is when you give a job to your OWN relative (specifically, a nephew).

Comment: +1 because I think *connected* is a better word to convey the probable reason for Peaches Geldof apparently being successful. On the other hand, the question title *did* specifically ask about getting a job because you're related to someone. I think the problem is OP himself isn't clear about what he means. Also note that the *nepotism-nephew* connection is etymological - it's irrelevant to current usage.

Comment: This is a good word too, though a little more general than nepotism

Answer (score 3):

On the east coast of Canada, this is generally referred to patronage.

Answer (score 1):

For some careers (actors, models, TV personalities, politicians), keeping your name in circulation is a large part of being successful. That's much easier to accomplish when your last name is already famous for some reason.

*Nepotism* to me implies that the powerful relative somehow *arranged* the job. In the particular example you cited, I doubt that's the case. The idea of some TV producer hiring a relative just because they are afraid of the enormous power of Bob Geldof is rather chuckle-worthy.

**I'd just put it down to *fame***. Another example I hear often is that it seems rather implausible that all four [Baldwin Brothers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baldwin_brothers) happened to be the most talented actors avialable for every part they were ever cast in. However, in the world they work in, a famous name is something that helps reassure investors (and puts butts in the seats).

Comment: "for some careers", also known as a form of branding... Sorry I haven't been more clear, however a quick comment

Answer (score -2):

*Simony* is applied mainly to the favouring of close associates financially, in a biased way. it has been adapted and used in the context of employing relatives as the result is the same.

Comment: Please delete your first answer, and improve your second post. Click on the  link which says "edit"